# auto select the parent after deleting a selected node

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I would like to auto select the parent after deleting a selected node.

The following is code that I use to delete a node and any children if there is any

```
           var selectedNode = treeview.select();
            $(selectedNode).children('.k-group').remove();
            treeview.remove(selectedNode);
```

How would I auto select the parent node after the delete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the folllowing:

```
var selectedNode = treeview.select();
var parentNode = treeview.parent(selectedNode);
$(selectedNode).children('.k-group').remove(); // you don't actually need this line of code
treeview.remove(selectedNode);
treeview.select(parentNode);
```

Take a look through the documentation too:

- http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/treeview#methods-parent
- http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/treeview#methods-select